# qml TextArea cursor delegate animation like Microsoft Word translating animation input

Tags: qml, textarea, qt6

I am going to coding qml input animation
I just use cursorDelegate，but I Dont know how to use animation to achieve

```
    TextArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        id: textArea
        width: 200
        height: 100
        text: "Hello World!"
        font.pixelSize: 20
        selectByMouse: true
        cursorPosition: 0
        cursorDelegate: Rectangle{
            id: cursor
            width: 10
            color: "black"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **SequentialAnimation** for that:

```
cursorDelegate: Rectangle {
        id: cursor
        width: 10
        color: "black"

        SequentialAnimation on color {
             loops: Animation.Infinite
             ColorAnimation { from: "transparent"; to: "black"; duration: 500 }
             ColorAnimation { from: "black"; to: "transparent"; duration: 500 }
         }
    }
```

Comment: I want to achieve Input move Animation， not like that

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you want to achieve.